# Typical efficiency of logical circuit outputs

Tags: digital-logic, output, efficiency, power-consumption

When looking at "logic" circuits (gates, level shifters, ...), usually intrinsic current consumption is specified, and is often quite low (compared to maximal recommended output currents of output pins).

However, they usually don't specify how the power consumption relates to input current.

Is there a rule of the thumb?

For example something like, if drawing x mA on the output pins, add 1.5*x to the consumption at Vdd pin.

I'm particularly interested in the case where components (ex : logic gate, isolator, ...) allow rather big currents (some are rated above 50mA) this component is directly connected to output, so the user might draw all that current. If the user draw max current, it's far from negligible, so the "efficiency" matters when sizing the DC/DC converters

Comment: When you say DC/DC converters, are you referring to the power supplies for these logic ICs?

Comment: Yes, I'm refering to the power supplies for these logic ICs (I have some voltage rails with significan power where logic circuits are negligible, but for others, like the 1.8V rail, most of the current is either ICs or pull-ups)

Comment: Except for Iq, it would be safe to assume current out = supply current. If you have more than one output, it's the sum of output currents.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to understand the relationship between output, input and operating (intrinsic) currents of ICs and such, and how they all combine to determine the total current that must be provided by their mutual power supply.

Here's an example of a system with a power supply, a couple of interconnected ICs and a user-installed load on the output (an LED and resistor):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm3ttI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've shown "intrinsic" operating current in orange, 5mA for IC1, 2mA for IC2, and these are currents which will be passed by the IC regardless of currents drawn into or out of any IC outputs or inputs.

The thing to grasp is that Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) requires that the total current flowing into a closed system, such as a node, or an IC, must equal the total current leaving it.

For IC1 you can see that the power supply pin, labelled Vcc (or sometimes Vdd), is where the IC draws all of the current it needs to operate (orange 5mA), and also all of the current that anything connected to its outputs will draw (black 1mA), totalling 6mA in. Just check for yourself that KCL is obeyed - the total leaving that IC must also be 6mA, via "out" and "GND".

For IC2, not only do you have an output supplying current for the LED, but you also have an input, which in this case is drawing in ("sinking") current via an input. Again, you can see that KCL is obeyed, always; the total current entering is 13mA, and the total current leaving is therefore also 13mA.

Ultimately the source of 5V (V1) powering this entire setup is also required to obey KCL, and must therefore be capable of supplying current to meet all these simultaneous demands, at any instant in time. In this case, that's 18mA right now.

Of course, demands change over time, sometimes the LED is off, sometimes the output of IC is sinking, not sourcing current, lots of things can change, and as they change, the total current supplied by V1 will vary.

It's up to you, the engineer and designer to ensure that your power supply is able to provide the *worst case maximum* current that this circuit *could possibly ever draw*, which includes currents needed by user-installed loads (like the LED).

Modern CMOS logic ICs only draw appreciable intrinsic supply current when they switch states, meaning that the higher the switching frequency, the more current they draw. Also, the input impedance on those devices is extremely high, and input current is mostly negligible at low frequencies, but those inputs have capacitance which must be charged and discharged, a current requirement which also increases with frequency. As the designer, you must consider all these sources of current requirements.

As far as "power consumption" is concerned, your requirement here would be provide a supply of 5V at 20mA (I added 2mA as a safety margin), which is \$5V \times 20mA = 100mW\$ at most.

If you suspect that the user might connect a heavier load instead of the LED (and IC2 is able to handle it), then you'll have to factor that into your power supply choice.

It's not clear what you mean by "efficiency", but if I assume you are talking  about power supply efficiency, then as long as you have a power supply with the requisite current capability your only worry is how hot the power supply will get while converting, say, 120V AC down to 5V DC. In this example, if your supply was 80% efficient in this conversion, then it would draw 125mW in, deliver 100mW out to your circuit, and waste the remaining 25mW as heat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My question is not about the efficiency of the DC/DC converters, but of the current efficiency of the ICs themselves. By this, I mean : If I change the resistor/LED so that I now have 20mA flowing through it, will the orange current remain 2mA, or will it inscrease? In the second case, by what order of magnitude (negligible compared to the extra 10mA at the output, or significantly?)

Comment: Probably intrinsic current will *not* remain constant for all output loads, especially if there is any internal feedback at work, which is often the case. Your use of the word "efficiency" is not appropriate in this context. Every system obeys KCL, and thus "current efficiency" is always 100%. No current is "lost". It's possible that intrinsic current can rise from 1mA to 2mA, as some output goes from 5mA to 10mA, for example, but at all times, the sum of all currents entering the device must equal the sum of all currents leaving it. Same for the power supply.

Comment: I'm using the word efficiency in the sense efficiency = usefull_output_current/total_input_current. In an ideal device without quiescent current, it would be 100%. In a real device, there is some current needed for internal work, that goes to ground and is therefore "waisted". If you have a better word, I'm interested

Answer (score 1):

A typical CMOS type logic input draws virtually no current at all when held static. They do have some leakage current, but that is in the order of one microamp, at worst case usage scenario, so in daily use you rarely even consider it.

And any current you draw from CMOS output will have to come from the supply. As per Kirchhoff's law for currents, any current taken from the output must cause an equal current taken from the supply.

What you may be missing is that most of the current consumption of CMOS circuits comes from dynamic consumption when a signal changes state. CMOS inputs are capacitive so changing the voltage needs a spike of current, and when the voltage is halfway both CMOS transistors are halfway on so there is also a spike of shoot-through current from supply to ground.

So the currents add up. Efficiency is another thing. CMOS transistors are not ideal, so for example a chip sinking in 4mA could have output voltage of 0.4V which measns 1.6mW lost to heat in the chip, and approximately it would have 100 ohm output impedance.

Other types of circuits than CMOS exist too, but CMOS is currently the most relevant technology.

Comment: I know that I need to add at least the output current (according to Kirchhoff's law for currents). The question is more about if the IC has to "sink" some aditionnal current just to make things work. But it's true that with CMOS technology, it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: For switching losses : indeed, they need to be taken into account for the few signals that are not very low frequency

Comment: @Sandro the answer is no. There is "voltage loss" - the pin voltage is lower than the supply voltage - but no "current loss".

Comment: @user253751 The chip needs a jolt of energy to toggle state. That is an additional current you may not expect, and so the chip will consume more current at high frequencies than at low frequencies. It also depends if there is capacitive load on output, as capacitances need to be charged and discharged. Even stray capacitances.

Comment: @Justme the question is about the effect on supply current of logic output current, not transition frequency

Comment: @user253751 The question is about what you have to take into consideration when using logic chips. A logic chip such as MCU uses more DC current at 10 MHz than 1 MHz and it will gulp a lot of current at the clock frequency. Therefore it matters. A logic chip that never toggles would be quite useless. For example even driving a piezo speaker at 440 Hz will consume a lot of peak current due to capacitive load, even if the logic chip itself consumes very little. At some level, these high peak currents need to be handled by the supply, as the peak duration is small compared to average current.

Comment: @Justme no, the question is specifically about current drawn from output pins. Did you read it?

Comment: @user253751 To be fair, I did read it. And my answer covers that case too. Did you read it? For CMOS there is no extra DC current, but for a toggling signal there is. For TTL, ECL or other logic types, the answer could be different.